# How to fully load an HTML5 video, when the page loads?

Tags: html, video, loading

I'm adding 4 videos to a page, using the "video" tag along with the "preload" attribute.
This works as expected, but I'm curious if there is a way to fully load the video on the background, even if the page takes a little longer to load.
What I want to accomplish is that the videos don't get interrupted by buffering, once you are playing them.
Thanks everybody.

Comment: So you want to completely download the video before it starts playing?

Comment: That is correct. I already started playing around with the "load()" method, but I have not been able to figure out when and if the video already loaded, because the "networkState" attribute never changes to 4. I'm using https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIDOMHTMLMediaElement as reference.

Comment: I am doubted its a good idea to download the full video before started playing. As video data is normally huge,HTML5 video format was designed so that browser can start playing the video before it is downloaded completely. Btw if you still need to load the video before playing I think the easiest way is to convert the video with [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) (without re-encoding), that will move the video meta info at the end of the video and browser won't start the video until it finds the meta info by fully downloading it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this might solved your issue @ [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_preload):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="auto">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

or go into detail for Preload @ [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/preload)